# Server 2012 Virtual SMTP Server not delivering messages

Tags: windows, smtp, windows-server-2012

I am having a problem with my Virtual SMTP server on Windows Server 2012 Standard.

I recently ported a clients Classic ASP hosting to a new server from a Server 2003 Standard box where the Classic ASP website was working fine. I had some problems getting the Classic ASP application to work on Server 2012 but once I changed my database connection string the site is working great.

I then attempted to get the SMTP virtual server working; the application uses CDOSYS to email error messages, customer requests and inquiries and lost password requests.

The virtual server was not working until I downloaded the Metabase Explorer and added the app pool identity and the IIS_IUSRS group to the SMTP keys in the metabase. The server is picking up the emails generated from the ASP script pages but they are not being delivered from the queue folder.

The badmail folder on the server did have a few error messages that indicated an SMTP 4.4.7 error.

I hope someone will have some ideas. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Though I did not receive any feedback from the community this problem was solved via my own research and Lunar Pages tech support. THe problem was solved by adding the actual server IP address to the DNS server which is hosted on the same server as the website, mail server and virtual smtp server. Apparently it was entered as "Localhost" and not the actual IP address. Not sure if it was 127.0.0.1 but that is what I am thinking. 
Kind Regards,
David